# Unit testing with Cosmos Db fails within Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have written unit test cases where I have my test cases written against Cosmos Db emulator. (Those who don't know what emulator is , it is a local development cosmos Db provided by Microsoft which are generally used to test your queries)

In my unit test case I am instantiating the Emulator db and then running the test cases. problem occurs when I push this changes to my Azure devops pipeline. there the test cases fails with error as

> Target machine actively refused the connection.

It does mean it is not able to instansiate db. How can i fix this. Any idea??

here is the initial code for testing

```
public class CosmosDataFixture : IDisposable
{
        public static readonly string CosmosEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
        public static readonly string EmulatorKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
        public static readonly string DatabaseId = "testdb";
        public static readonly string RecordingCollection = "testcolec";
        public static string Root = Directory.GetParent( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ).Parent.Parent.FullName;
        public static DocumentClient client { get; set; }
public async Task ReadConfigAsync()
        {

          //  StartEmulatorDatabaseFromPowerShell();
            client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
                 new ConnectionPolicy
                 {
                     ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                     ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

                 } );
            await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId } );
            await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
                new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } );
            await ReadAllData( client );
        }
     public CosmosDataFixture()
        {
                      
            ReadConfigAsync();     
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
          DeleteDatabaseFromPowerShell();// this is also defined in above class
        }
    }   
    public class CosmosDataTests : IClassFixture<CosmosDataFixture>
    { // mu unit test case goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this statement to your `yaml` Pipeline:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
      Start-CosmosDbEmulator
```

And the Connection String for *CosmosDB* should be: `AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==`

You can instantiate the CosmosDB client like that:

```cs
var connectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
var client = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
var database = client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("testdb");
var container = await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("testcolec", "/partitionKey");
```

Comment: where do I need connection string?and above powershell cmdlet when run locally prompts a yes/no window and after selecting Yes The emulator instansiate. how it will be handeled in above Yaml above

Comment: If you want to run your unit test within your CI pipeline, you need to add the Powershell script to that DevOps Pipeline.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd

Comment: it still fails and it takes my original production Db and run the query against it. it doesnt hit the emulator. How can I check if the import of Module has been done?

Comment: you have to use the connection string for the cosmosdb emulator within your unit tests.

Comment: you have mentioned instantiating cosmos db client. but i am already doing it in my code if you see.. so I dont need the way you mentioned. correct me if I am wrong. when I run it locally it works, that is db and collectionis created

Comment: also in the link they have asked for the extension which is available in Market place.. but this extension is not available when writing your yaml task

Comment: i thought the section for yaml pipelines would help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd#add-the-task-using-yaml

Comment: The Powershell command should be before or after the cosmos db emulator task??

Comment: I tried by adding Powershell task first and then Run Azure cosmos Db , I get error as "failed to create endpoint azure-cosmosdb-emulator on network nat: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." not sure which process is being used here??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234420/discussion-between-derdani81-and-zzzsharepoint).